# Why do I get TypeError: $.ajax is not a function when I make an Ajax Request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm building an application and when I make an Ajax request to the server I get the following error:

> TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

I checked online and especially on Stackoverflow, discovering a lot of questions asked by people with my same problem but none of the accepted answers solved my problem:

- I have a *not* slim version of jQuery included in my HTML
- I included the jQuery's source file *before* the inclusion of the javascript which contains my function
- I think there's no mistake in parentheses, as in some of the questions

This is how I have included jQuery:

```
<script src="./src/jquery-3.2.1.js"> type="text/javascript"</script>
```

I attach part of the code for clarity:

```
function verifyUsername(success, error) {
  console.log("start check complete");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/username',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      username: document.getElementById("username").value
    }),
    done: /*success*/ alert("OK"),
    fail: /*error*/ alert("NO")
  });
}

function verifyBirthPlace(success, error) {
  console.log("pl check complete");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/birthplace',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      birthplace_provincia: document.getElementById("birthProvince").value,
      birthplace: document.getElementById("birthTown").value
    }),
    done: success,
    fail: error
  });
}

function checkRegistration() {

  verifyUsername(
    verifyBirthPlace(
      function() {

        if (checkPwdStrenght() == false || comparePwds() == false || checkDate() == false || checkTaxCode() == false) {
          console.log("f")
          return false;
        } else {
          console.log("t")
          return true;
        }
      },
      function(data) {
        console.log("error from place" + data);
      })

    ,
    function(data) {
      console.log("ERROR from user" + data);
    });
}
```

For now I have only console logs instead of the real behaviour of the functions because I'm still stuck with the Ajax error. `checkRegistration()` is called on click in the HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="subSignUp" onclick="checkRegistration()">Submit</button>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is the code above inside of $( document ).ready() ? https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @joe.dawley that's irrelevant. It's a function that gets called on the click of a button, at which point the DOM is surely ready.

Comment: No, but I tried to add this (as suggested in some of the answers) $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($.ajax);
  }); and I got "undefined" in console

Comment: @M-elman do you include something that redefines `$`? Maybe even another version of jQuery?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca too right, I missed that.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, these are my only javascript inclusions in the HTML, in this order: <script src="./src/jquery-3.2.1.js"> type="text/javascript"</script>
  <script src="/src/utility.js"></script>

Comment: I don't think you need `.` before `src` in the jQuery link ... and the tags aren't right

Comment: `<script src="./src/jquery-3.2.1.js"> type="text/javascript"</script>` if it's really like this I wonder if maybe you shouldn't remove that `type="text/javascript"` from **between** those tags

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You're right, I hadn't it and I added it later after I saw some of the answers online, but I wrote it wrong. Anyway, removing it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: jQuery isn't loading - are you sure the script file is loading properly? If you view your network panel in your developer tools, is that resource loading properly?  Have you verified the contents of that file is actually the jQuery library?

Comment: There seems to be problem with the path. I have tried running your code it runs fine if you have the jquery file in the correct place.
Can you please share the folder/path structure of how you are referring this jquery file from the source file?

Comment: @cale_b your suggestion has been fundamental to solve the issue: viewing the network panel I noticed that a slim version of jQuery was loaded even if I did not include it, as @ Federicoklezculloca pointed out some comments above. That was surely because I used an automated tool to build my HTML. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Good to know :) As a side note, why are some people suggesting to try to do the ajax call inside `$(document).ready()`? `$` is not part of the DOM, and if you can call `$(document).ready()`, guess what, `$` has already been defined! You're calling it! :)

Answer (score -3):

The function needs to self-invoke, for some reason. That is:

```
(function($) {
    $.ajax(/* etc. */)
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Calling on $(document).ready console.log($); returns me "function r()" and console.log(typeOf($)) returns me "function"

Comment: What is the type of $.ajax? My hunch is that it does need to be inside a $(document).ready just so jQuery is aware of the call.

Comment: The type of $.ajax is "undefined". Note that I inserted only these logs in the $(document).ready and not my functions